# how to redirect to login page for users who are not logged in when they want to post

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am creating a site where user will be posting their stuff, in order to post to the site it requires to login, so for those who are not logged in when they want to post I want them to be redirected to the login page and a displaying pop up message "Post require login"

This is for python 3.7.3 and django 2.2.3. For users who are not logged in, I have added @login_required which throw an error page not found, instead of that I want to redirect them to login form.

Views.py for posting

```
@login_required
def PostNew(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect('loststuffapp:IndexView')
else:
    form = PostForm()
return render(request, 'loststuffapp/form.html', {'form': form})
```

views.py for login

```
def login_request(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    user_form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        username = user_form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = user_form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
            return redirect("loststuffapp:IndexView")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")
user_form = AuthenticationForm()
return render(request,
              "loststuffapp/login.html",
              {"user_form":user_form}
    )
```

login.html

```
{% extends "loststuffapp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
   <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{user_form.as_p}}
       <p><button class="btn" type="submit" >Login</button></p>
       <p>If you already have an account, <a href="/login"><strong>register</strong></a> instead</p>
{% endblock %}
```

form.html

```
{% extends 'loststuffapp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>New post</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
       <p><button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Post</button></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

         path('', views.IndexView, name="IndexView"),
         path('IndexView', views.IndexView, name="IndexView"),
         path('PostNew/', views.PostNew, name="PostNew"),
         path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
         path('logout/', views.logout_request, name="logout"),
         path('login/', views.login_request, name="login"),
         path('ContactForm/', views.ContactForm, name="ContactForm"),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('loststuffapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your [**`LOGIN_URL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#login-url) in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'  # or use login url name "login"
```

Comment: Thansk for a reply, I have done that but no changes

Comment: can you please share your urls.py?

Comment: Have you added `LOGIN_URL='/login/'` in settings.py :) ?

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, also I want to display a pop message, now am wondering which part of views I need to write login function or PostNew function

Comment: you can write a decorator :)